# Change Clauses Order Prolog [Database Manipulation]

Tags: prolog

I have do implement a rule `invert(+PredicateSymbol, +Arity)` that reverses the order of the predicates PredicateSymbol/Arity on the data base.

For example:

before:

```
vote(john, ['A'-7, 'B'-9, 'C'-6]).
vote(jack, ['A'-8, 'B'-8, 'C'-7]).
vote(peter, ['C'-4, 'D'-7, 'E'-3]).
vote(harry, ['A'-7, 'C'-6]).
vote(richard, ['A'-10, 'D'-10, 'F'-9]).

| ?- invert(vote,2).
yes
```

after:

```
vote(richard, ['A'-10, 'D'-10, 'F'-9]).
vote(harry, ['A'-7, 'C'-6]).
vote(peter, ['C'-4, 'D'-7, 'E'-3]).
vote(jack, ['A'-8, 'B'-8, 'C'-7]).
vote(john, ['A'-7, 'B'-9, 'C'-6]).
```

I have no clue how to do this since it must invert any clause with its given arity...

Comment: Notice that `asserta/1` and `assertz/1` insert things into the database first and last, respectively.

Comment: Yes @DanielLyons I know  that, but how do I declare the Predicate as dynamic inside invert?

Comment: You 100% cannot change the predicate to dynamic inside another predicate. Declarations go outside predicates. Are you sure you have to do this? It's kind of gross, maybe you just need to _display_ them in reverse order?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure that it must be done this way... I must reverse a queried predicated

Comment: In that case, you probably need to use `findall/3` in conjunction with some of the [program examination predicates](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=examineprog) to obtain the bodies; `retract/1` and `retractall/1` will probably be useful as well.

Comment: `abolish/1` may be used for that rather unusual purpose, but ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions to this problem.

1)

As long as your predicate is dynamic AND composed by simple facts (no head :- body clauses), this works:

```
reverse(F/A) :-
    functor(Pred,F,A),
    retract(Pred),
    asserta(Pred),
    fail.
reverse(_).
```

For example:

```
?- reverse(vote/2).
true.

?- vote(X,_).
X = richard ;
X = harry ;
X = peter ;
X = jack ;
X = john.
```

2)

If your intention is to get predicate solutions in reverse order, this works for ANY predicate with a finite number of solutions:

```
revaux([_|Rest],Next) :-
    revaux(Rest,Next).
revaux([X|_],X).

reverse_order(Pred) :-
    copy_term(Pred,QueryPred),
    findall(QueryPred,QueryPred,AllSols),
    !,
    revaux(AllSols,Pred).
```

For example:

```
?- vote(X,_).
X = john ;
X = jack ;
X = peter ;
X = harry ;
X = richard.

?- reverse_order(vote(X,_)).
X = richard ;
X = harry ;
X = peter ;
X = jack ;
X = john.
```

Comment: There is already a Prolog predicate `reverse/2` so you don't need `revaux/2`.

Comment: Solved it! Thanks. Do you know if there is any way to declare a predicate as dynamic inside reverse? @Zebollo Or this is that impossible to do?